# Receiving 'end of statement is expected' in vb script

Tags: vb.net

The following script is giving me the 'end of statement is expected' error at line 5.  I have other similar scripts that run properly, but do not have the 3rd line.  I have lines that do not have an item id, which is why I put line 2 in there.  Sorry if it's messy - I'm very new at this!

```
Private Sub Export_BeforePrint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs)
    If GetCurrentColumnValue("IMA_ItemID") Is Nothing Or GetCurrentColumnValue("IMA_ItemID") IsDBNull Then
        Me.Export.text = "" _
    ElseIf GetCurrentColumnValue("IMA_ItemID") isnotnull AND GetCurrentColumnValue("IMA_CountryOfOrigin") = "USA" Then
        Me.Export.text = "*** These commodities, technology, or software were exported from the United States in accordance with the Export Administration Regulations.  Diversion contrary to United States law is prohibited."
    Else
        Me.Export.text = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

Before I put in the line 2, it looked like this.  However, then I was getting an error when printing when the itemid was null:

```
Private Sub Export_BeforePrint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs)
    If GetCurrentColumnValue("IMA_CountryOfOrigin") = "USA" Then
        Me.Export.text = "*** These commodities, technology, or software were exported from the United States in accordance with the Export Administration Regulations.  Diversion contrary to United States law is prohibited."
    Else
        Me.Export.text = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks

Here is the code without the line numbers.  Sorry - I thought that would make it easier to understand my question:  and thank you jmcilhinney - I changed my isnotnull to isnot nothing.

```
Private Sub Export_BeforePrint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs)
    If GetCurrentColumnValue("IMA_ItemID") Is Nothing Or GetCurrentColumnValue("IMA_ItemID") IsDBNull Then
        Me.Export.text = "" _
    elseIf GetCurrentColumnValue("IMA_ItemID") IsNot Nothing _
            AND GetCurrentColumnValue("IMA_CountryOfOrigin") = "USA" _ 
        Then 
            Me.Export.text = "*** These commodities, technology, or software were exported from the United States in accordance with the Export Administration Regulations.  Diversion contrary to United States law is prohibited."
        Else 
            Me.Export.text = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you Paste your real code and not an amemded version with line numbers that makes everything unreadable?

Comment: There's no such thing as `isnotnull` in VB.NET.  Did you mean `IsNot Nothing` or perhaps `IsNot DBNull.Value` if is a database null?

Comment: remove the `_` at the end of line 3

Comment: when I remove the _ from line 3, I still get the same error, plus a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Export_BeforePrint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs)
    If GetCurrentColumnValue("IMA_ItemID") <> DBNull.Value AndAlso 
            GetCurrentColumnValue("IMA_CountryOfOrigin").ToString = "USA" Then
        Me.Export.text = "*** These commodities, technology, or software were exported from the United States in accordance with the Export Administration Regulations.  Diversion contrary to United States law is prohibited."
    Else
        Me.Export.text = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

`DbNull` is different type than `Nothing`. You can check for it with

```
If dataRow.IsNull("IMA_ItemID")
```

or

```
If dataRow("IMA_ItemID") = DBNull.Value
```

Comment: Slight change - had to change <> DBNull.Value to isnot Nothing and then it worked great!  Thanks again everyone!